# How to Reproduce Issue from Windows Update Gradual Rollout Phase on Test Distribution

Tags: device-driver, windows-update

We are developing a `UMDF` device driver that has passed the necessary `HLK` tests and even Windows Update on test distribution does not seem to show and errors after the update. But in the actual driver submission to Windows Update, on the `Gradual Rollout` phase, a large number of users have encountered `CM_PROB_FAILED_POST_START (error code 43)` enough to pause the driver distribution and reject it eventually.

Is there a better way of simulating/reproducing this Gradual Rollout issue safely, aside from putting the driver into Windows Update test distribution? From our checking, entries in the driver install logs `(C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log)` always result `SUCCESS`, with return codes from each setup phase returning 0x0. `EventViewer` also show no signs of driver failure or warning. Are there anymore things that could be useful in finding out if Code 43 has occurred on the devices?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the driver in question can only support a specific brand of component, and causes unsupported brands to fail. Therefore there is a need to modify its `CHID` mapping to increase specificity and limit the installation only to qualified systems.

Flight Performance was a great source of information regarding the Gradual Rollout failures.